# Regex to ignore unwanted matched quotes

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to split several key-value lines with regular expression in Python.
The file I'm working have more than 1.2M lines, so I created another one with a few lines that suits all different key-value's occurrences I need to care about:

```
@=""
@="0"
@="="
@="@"
@="k=\"v\""
@=dword:00000000
@=hex:00
"k"=""
"k"="="
"k"="@"
"k"="k=\"v\""
"k"="v"
"k"=dword:00000000
"k"=hex:00
"k=\"v\""=""
"k=\"v\""="="
"k=\"v\""="@"
"k=\"v\""="k=\"v\""
"k=\"v\""="v"
"k=\"v\""=dword:00000000
"k=\"v\""=hex:00
```

I'm already doing the job with a fairly simple look-behind/look-ahead regex that works like a charm:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
regex = re.compile(r'(?<=@|")=(?=[dh"])')

for line in open('split-test'):
    line = line.strip()
    key, value = regex.split(line, 1)

    if key != '@':
        key = key[1:-1]

print '{} => {}'.format(key, value)
```

Output:

```
@ => ""
@ => "0"
@ => "="
@ => "@"
@ => "k=\"v\""
@ => dword:00000000
@ => hex:00
k => ""
k => "="
k => "@"
k => "k=\"v\""
k => "v"
k => dword:00000000
k => hex:00
k=\"v\" => ""
k=\"v\" => "="
k=\"v\" => "@"
k=\"v\" => "k=\"v\""
k=\"v\" => "v"
k=\"v\" => dword:00000000
k=\"v\" => hex:00
```

As you can see, in the code flow I'll have to strip the leading and trailing quotes from the key part.
That said, I've to state that I'm not trying to optimize anything, I'm just trying to learn how I can achieve the same results with the regular expression itself.

I've tried many changes in the above original code, and I successfully got a new horrible-and-slow-but-working regexp with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
regex = re.compile(r'(?:(@)|(?:"((?:(?:[^"\\]+)|\\.)*)"))=')

for line in open('split-test'):
    line = line.strip()
    key, value = filter(None, regex.split(line))

    print '{} => {}'.format(key, value)
```

Here I'd have to use `filter()` 'cause it matches some empty strings. I'm not a regular expression master, so I'm just wondering any better written regex that would do this job.

Comment: Was difficult to choose only one answer given the fact that all of them were helpful, but as we must choose only one I'll accept Allan Moore's answer for 1) not being too permissive in key matching, 2) not match key quotes and 3) being fast as original attempt. Tryph's answer also did the job fast, but although it worked, isn't guaranteed it will always work as expected being too permisive. sin's answer gave a nice error-proof matching, but in the end it doubled the overall parse time. Again, thank you all for your effort, I've learned many new things in this question! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a regex that scrapes off the quotes in the process of matching?  Check this out:

```
r'^(")?((?(1)[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*|@))"?=([dh"].+$)'
```

If the first character is a quote, it gets captured in group #1, the `(1)` condition succeeds, and the YES branch of the conditional consumes everything up to the next unescaped quote (but not the quote itself).  If not, the NO branch tries to match `@`.  Either way, the key gets captured in group #2, without enclosing quotes.

The rest of the regex is straightforward: it consumes the trailing quote (if there is one) and the `=`, and then the rest of the string gets captured in group #3.  Note that it could match malformed inputs that start with `@"` or `""`.  If that's not acceptable, you can add a lookahead to validate the format before the actual matching starts.  I didn't bother because the extra clutter would get in the way of explaining the core technique.

```
^
(")?
(
  (?(1)
    [^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*
    |
    @
  )
)
"?
=
([dh"].+$)
```

Comment: Whoa, it really works and it's fast as the original code! I even knew it was possible to use regular expression conditions like this... learned many tricks in this question! :)

Comment: Or, if Python has branch reset   ^(?|"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|(@))=([dh"].+)$   might work too.

Answer (score 3):

may this do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
string = r"""@=""
@="0"
@="="
@="@"
@="k=\"v\""
@=dword:00000000
@=hex:00
"k"=""
"k"="="
"k"="@"
"k"="k=\"v\""
"k"="v"
"k"=dword:00000000
"k"=hex:00
"k=\"v\""=""
"k=\"v\""="="
"k=\"v\""="@"
"k=\"v\""="k=\"v\""
"k=\"v\""="v"
"k=\"v\""=dword:00000000
"k=\"v\""=hex:00
"""
regex = re.compile(r'("?)(.*)\1=(["hd].+)')

results = regex.findall(string)
for _, key, value in results:
    print '{} => {}'.format(key, value)
```

it gives the result below:

```
@ => ""
@ => "0"
@ => "="
@ => "@"
@ => "k=\"v\""
@ => dword:00000000
@ => hex:00
k => ""
k => "="
k => "@"
k => "k=\"v\""
k => "v"
k => dword:00000000
k => hex:00
k=\"v\" => ""
k=\"v\" => "="
k=\"v\" => "@"
k=\"v\" => "k=\"v\""
k=\"v\" => "v"
k=\"v\" => dword:00000000
k=\"v\" => hex:00
```

Comment: Yay, this indeed do the trick nicely better than my horrible-and-slow attempt. Seems to be fairly permissive although apparently does not cause any unwanted behavior. I liked! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track with your last regex that tries to resolve quotes.
This uses capture buffers instead of split.

There are two ways to go.

Assume quotations are imperfect (unbalanced) -

```
 #  ^((?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|.)*)=((?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^=])*)$

 ^
 (                         # (1 start)
      (?:
           "
           [^"\\]* 
           (?: \\ . [^"\\]* )*
           "
        |  .
      )*
 )                         # (1 end)
 =
 (                         # (2 start)
      (?:
           "
           [^"\\]* 
           (?: \\ . [^"\\]* )*
           "
        |  [^=]
      )*
 )                         # (2 end)
 $
```

or, assume they are perfect -

```
 #  ^((?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^"])*)=((?:"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^="])*)$

 ^
 (                         # (1 start)
      (?:
           "
           [^"\\]* 
           (?: \\ . [^"\\]* )*
           "
        |  [^"]
      )*
 )                         # (1 end)
 =
 (                         # (2 start)
      (?:
           "
           [^"\\]* 
           (?: \\ . [^"\\]* )*
           "
        |  [^="]
      )*
 )                         # (2 end)
 $
```

Comment: This is why we all love regexes: it's the ease of writing and maintenance.

Comment: Yeah, the second one seems to do a perfect strictly-match against the lines, even though it also includes leading/trailing quotes of key part. Is there any way to not include them in the matches? Anyway it's more error-proof than my original attempt, I really liked that! :)

Comment: @Paulot Freitas - Nah, because all the quotes are parsed as if its already been parsed by the language and internalized as a string variable. If you are concerned, just strip off outer quote pairs when you process the capture buffers.